# Cannot call function from a class function that is defined in the same class

Tags: php, oop

I cannot seem to call a function from a function within a class. I've created some helper functions to help me do math on the current object but I can't seem to access any functions, even if they are defined and called in the same class.

I've tried using: `$this->b();` I have also tried `self::b();` from within the a() function but I get the same error everytime.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function b()

```
class test{
  function a(){
    $a = b();
    return $a;
  }
  function b(){
    return 'testing';
  }
}
```

when I call the class function using:

```
$obj = new test();
$value = $obj::a();
echo $value;
```

I do not receive anything back but an error saying the function does not exist.

I just need to access functions from within a class, I don't know what else to try this is very easy in a lot of other programming languages, what am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Read the manual and you would eventually get to `$this->b()`

Comment: I Tried that, and within my question I also specified that. Same error. Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function b()

Comment: And as the `a` method is not defined as static `$value = $obj->a();`

Comment: I've made the suggested changes, same error.

Comment: See the code in my answer

Comment: **And please DO NOT change the question once an answer has been provided** It makes the comments and answers look foolish

Comment: @RiggsFolly Real rich huh? They went and deleted their account.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I am thinking of a word ...... Can you guess what it is?

Comment: @RiggsFolly More than one actually.

Answer (score -1):

To call a method in the same class as the calling method use `$this->`
If the class is instantiated and not static you also use `->` and not the `::`

See annotations for changes

```
class test{
  function a(){
    $a = $this->b();        // changed
    return $a;
  }
  function b(){
    return 'testing';
  }
}

$obj = new test();
$value = $obj->a();         // changed
echo $value;
```

Tested Result:

```
testing
```

If you wanted the class to be static as it appears from the code change you made in your question then this is the way

```
class test{
  static function a(){
    $a = self::b();        
    return $a;
  }
  static function b(){
    return 'testing';
  }
}

//$obj = new test();
//$value = $obj::a();         
$value = test::a();         
echo $value;
```

Also tested result

```
testing
```

Comment: I've tried both `$value = $obj->a();` and I have also tried `$value = $obj::a();` same error.

Comment: Then something else is going on in your code as I just ran this to be absolutely sure it worked

Comment: I assume you did see the **two** changes I made

Comment: I sure did. I've tried all the combinations, currently trying again for the 10th time. this is driving me nuts. I also am working in WP if that has anythng to do with the weirdness. My class is autoloaded. I am able to set values on my object and initialize it, but accessing functions from within the class are undefined. I mean this isn't rocket science I've been doing OOP for a long time with .net

Comment: So I added the way it would work if the class was STATIC to my answer